# How can I publish an html5 banner ad for Google Adwords in Adobe Animate DC without Google adwords rejecting it?

Tags: google, adobe-animate

How can I publish an html5 banner ad for Google Adwords without Google adwords rejecting it?

I tried every tutorial I can find and it is showing errors like this:
[image]

I tried copying and pasting these lines on my index.html code but when I open my html my ad doesn't show.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, You need local versions of those files in your zip folder and your html needs to point to the local versions. You can't have .js files hosted elsewhere.